# How to ignore high deviations in a list

Tags: python, numpy, math, data-science, standard-deviation

There are lists like `[2.1, 2.01, 6, 2.2, 1.9]` and `[2, 7.1, 7.2, 6.9]`
Is there a function in numpy (or other library) to remove numbers which deviate more than 5% from the other numbers. In these cases it would be 6 and 2.

The list size isnt fixed. Nor the numbers range.

Thanks

Comment: You could code this function by yourself, but you need to be clear on the reference number you want. Because in the second list you could as well say 7.1, 7.2 and 6.9 deviate from 2 and should be ignored. How to choose that reference?

Comment: Guessing that with `deviate more than 5% from the other numbers` you mean some statistic, as the std. Just do it yourself, compute the std and remove those values that are above the std times a certain value, or some similar euristic. There are plenty of examples of outlier removal here in SO.

Comment: Didnt know they were called outliers. Thanks @yatu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy
data = [2.1, 2.01, 6, 2.2, 1.9]

elements = numpy.array(data)

mean = numpy.mean(elements, axis=0)
sd = numpy.std(elements, axis=0)
final_list = [x for x in data if (x > mean - 1 * sd)]
final_list = [x for x in final_list if (x < mean + 1 * sd)]
print(final_list)
```

```
[2.1, 2.01, 2.2, 1.9]
```

Source: https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/02/removing-outliers-standard-deviation-python.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using `scipy.stats.zscore`:

```
from scipy.stats import zscore
a = np.array([2.1, 2.01, 6, 2.2, 1.9])
print(a[np.abs(zscore(a)) < max(a) / 5])
```

Output:

```
[ 2.1   2.01  2.2   1.9 ]
```